# Open a popUp in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to open a popup when I click a button on react, I have this but the popUp wont appear:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target={`#${props.idMessage}`}>
                {props.idMessage}
            </button>


            <div class="modal fade" id={props.idMessage} tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Using the react debug tools I can see that the props.id obviously differ from each one and the value on my data-target is the same of my id, as you can see the popUp should appear:

[image]

Comment: hello, i don't know which library you are using but there are lots of react ui libraries out there that are easier to use that instead of using the attributes, we should be using props and state, after all we are in jsx scope not html anymore making logic like this easier to implement. Try this: https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/dialogs

Answer (score 5):

Here is modern way to achieve this using React Hooks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const PopUp = ({ idMessage }) => {
  // create state `open` with default as false
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      {/* click of button toggles `open` value therefore visibility */}
      <button
        onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target={`#${idMessage}`}
      >
        {idMessage}
      </button>
      {/* If open is true show your <div /> */}
      {open && (
        <div
          className="modal fade"
          id={idMessage}
          tabIndex="-1"
          role="dialog"
          aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
          aria-hidden="true"
        >
          content
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default PopUp;
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to react, so maybe this is a dumb question. I've copied this code into a file and called it from the return of another component that is rendered. In this case, the element is just rendered in the same component, but not opened into a popup. Could you help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Hey, this is just an example of open/close functionality, to make it look like a pop up your div must be styled. So in this case classes "modal fade" have styles on them centering the div to the page and fade animation.

Comment: This is exactly how I am doing it as well.  However, I have noticed that sometimes it can "break" when clicking all over the screen or rapidly clicking the button.  Not sure why it does that.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider creating the popup as a re-usable component, that just renders the `props.message`.
Suppose you have the button in App.js, here is how you can add the click listener on it.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {showPopup: false};

  openPopupHandler = () => {
    this.setState({showPopup: true});
  }
  
  closePopupHandler = () => {
    this.setState({showPopup: false});
  }

  
  render() {
    let popup = null;
    if(this.state.showPopup) {
      popup = (<Popup message='the text you need to display' closeMe={this.closePopupHandler}/>);
    } 
    return(
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.clicked}>Click me </button>
      {popup}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And you can define the popup component as given below.

Popup.js

```
const popup = (props) => {
return (
  <div>
    <p>{props.message}</p>
    <button onClick={props.closeMe}>Close Popup</button>
  </div>
);
}
```

Also, style the popup component with the size as per your requirement and with an z-index greater than that of the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
class PopUp extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        hide: false
    };
 }
 clicked(){
     this.setState({
       hide: true
     });
 }
 render() {
     return (
        <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onClick={() => this.clicked()} >
            Click Me
        </button>
        {
          this.state.hide? 
              <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">Required PopUp </div>
              : null
        }
        </div>
     );
  }
}
```

> you can use this as `<PopUp>` in your code